# UWP CommandBar moves vertically when IsOpen changes

Tags: xaml, uwp, commandbar

I have come across a layout / template problem with [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) of which symptoms are seen in several pages:

- [UWP - CommandBar blank space under Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176836/uwp-commandbar-blank-space-under-buttons)
- https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1024

It seems that the UWP `CommandBar` elements inside the `CommandBar` have an actual height of 44px, which is cropped in a control of 40px.

- When `IsOpen="False"`, the `AppBarButton`s are vertically centered and the bottom 4px of the `CommandBar.Content` section is not shown
- When `IsOpen="Top"`, the `AppBarButton`s are shifted up, an [ugly gap appears under them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176836/uwp-commandbar-blank-space-under-buttons) and the bottom 4px of the `CommandBar.Content` section is suddenly shown

Besides the ugly gap, it makes it very difficult to correctly vertically center elements in `CommandBar.Content`.

About the vertical position of the `CommandBar`

- When the CommandBar is at the top of the Page, the CommandBar itself does not vertically resize.
- When the CommandBar is at the bottom of the Page, the CommandBar itself grows vertically with 4px.
- In all cases, the other symptoms happen

## At bottom of page

[image: Visual reproduction at bottom of Page]
The red line visualizes the bottom 4px of the `CommandBar.Content` section. Also, with the `Reveal` effect to the left of the mouse cursor you can see that the buttons shift up. The whole CommandBar grows vertically

## At top of page

[image: Visual reproduction at top of Page]

## Trying to vertically align the content (hint: does not work)

[image: Visual reproduction at bottom of Page with vertical content alignment]

## Question

Is there any way to workaround this issue? Microsoft has [qualified this more than a year ago as something they **might** fix in WinUI 3](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1024) which is far away.

## Bug repro repository

https://github.com/hansmbakker/CommandBar.BugRepro

## Relevant code to reproduce

```xml
<Page x:Class="CommandBar.BugRepro.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:CommandBar.BugRepro"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                    Background="#BB555555"
                    DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
            <AppBarButton Icon="Back"
                          Label="Back" />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Save"
                          Label="Save" />
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarButton Label="Title" />
            <AppBarButton Label="Description" />
            <AppBarButton Label="Pictures"
                          Icon="Pictures" />
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Rectangle Fill="Red"
                           Height="4"
                           Width="200" />
            </CommandBar.Content>
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Setting"
                              Label="Settings">
                    <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                        <KeyboardAccelerator Modifiers="Control"
                                             Key="I" />
                    </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
                </AppBarButton>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UWP CommandBar moves vertically when IsOpen changes

During the testing, `AppBarSeparator` cause this behavior. Currently there is a work around that could fix this, please give `AppBarSeparator` specific height less than 40px.

```
<AppBarSeparator Height="40"/>
```

Comment: that works! Thank you!
@Nico Zhu - MSFT can you ensure Microsoft picks this up as a bug and solves it, so that the workaround is not needed anymore?

Comment: Sure, and you could also post this behavior with windows feed back app.